# count co-occurrences of values in dataframe r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a sample data frame as follows and I need to explore the ***Category*** column.

```
> df
  Id  Category
  1 [1,2,3,4]
  2   [2,3,5]
  3   [1,4,5]
  4   [1,2,5]
  5       [4]
  6   [2,3,5]
  7     [1,5]
```

In reality, there are thousands of rows in the data frame with categories between 1 to 25. I want to see how many times these categories co-occurred in that column. The output should be as a matrix or data frame.

**Matrix Output:**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    2    1    2    3
[2,]    2    0    3    1    3
[3,]    1    3    0    1    2
[4,]    2    1    1    0    1
[5,]    3    3    2    1    0
```

**Dataframe Output:**

```
     C1 C2     Count
     1  2      2
     1  3      1
     1  4      2
     1  5      3
     2  3      3
     2  4      1
     2  5      3
     3  4      1
     3  5      2
     4  5      1
```

Can anybody help me in this regard?

Comment: We need a `dput(df)` since we do not know exactly how your data is stored in R

Comment: every cell in Category is a string value. We need to split it first and then count

Comment: The output is just for understanding, I made it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `crossprod` with `table` after splitting the 'Category' column with `strsplit` (using only `base R` functions)

```
out <- crossprod(table(subset(stack(setNames(lapply(strsplit(df$Category, 
    "[][]|,\\s*"), trimws), df$Id))[2:1], nzchar(values))))
diag(out) <- 0
```

-output

```
> out
      values
values 1 2 3 4 5
     1 0 2 1 2 3
     2 2 0 3 1 3
     3 1 3 0 1 2
     4 2 1 1 0 1
     5 3 3 2 1 0
```

In the above code, we extract the numeric part by splitting on the `,` and `[]` in `strsplit`, set the names of the returning `list` with `Id` column, `stack` the `named` `list` to a two column data.frame (`stack`), use `table` to get the frequency count and then wrap with `crossprod` on the `table` output.  The `diag`onals are then replaced with 0

---

If we need the long format data.frame, then `replace` one of the triangular matrix to 0, before converting to `table` and `subset`ing after wrapping with `as.data.frame`

```
out2 <-  subset(as.data.frame.table(replace(out, upper.tri(out), 
     0)), Freq != 0)
row.names(out2) <- NULL
colnames(out2) <- c("C1", "C2", "Count")
```

-output

```
> out2
   C1 C2 Count
1   2  1     2
2   3  1     1
3   4  1     2
4   5  1     3
5   3  2     3
6   4  2     1
7   5  2     3
8   4  3     1
9   5  3     2
10  5  4     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = 1:7, Category = c("[1,2,3,4]", "[2,3,5]", 
"[1,4,5]", "[1,2,5]", "[4]", "[2,3,5]", "[1,5]")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working. I'll appreciate you, if you explain the working of each function.

Comment: How I can see the unique categories in that column?

Comment: In the generated matrix, row names are duplicated. Means the values are duplicated. Can you check it again.

Comment: @abdulsamad is it the matrix or the three column data.frame

Comment: matrix that you generated as out

Comment: @abdulsamad the `out` looks like the same as your expected output except that yours didn't had a dimnames

Comment: @abdulsamad Also, the long format is also now matching with your expected.  Maybe your expected showed in the post is not correct then

Comment: I got where it's happening. When we make the stack, it shows the duplicated values in the Values column, where each value (from 0 to 29) appears twice with space and without space. Therefore it's duplicated. Can you please rewrite the code? Therefore I'm getting 58 values instead of 29 like

"0", " 0", "1"," 1" etc

Comment: @abdulsamad sorry, it is not clear.  Is this based on the data in my post or yours?

Comment: @abdulsamad I changed to add `\\s*` in the split code if your data have spaces.  This is why the dput is important

Comment: Yes, it's based on the actual data I have. Actually, issue is in the regular expression. It splits the first value correctly without space, but added space in all the remaining values of that cell.  For example

`[[668]]
[1] ""    "5"   " 26"

[[669]]
[1] ""    "2"   " 9"  " 17"

[[670]]
[1] ""    "5"   " 9"  " 15" " 20" " 21" " 26" " 29"`

Comment: @abdulsamad try with `trimws` as in the update.  It is better to show example with dput so that we know the structure correctly.  In the example you showed, there was no spaces after or before the `,`

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. `\\s*`  is best option

Answer (score 1):

another option:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Category = list(reticulate::py_eval(Category))) %>%
  unnest(Category) %>%
  table()  %>%
  crossprod() %>%
  as.data.frame.table() %>%
  filter(Category!=Category.1)

   Category Category.1 Freq
1         2          1    2
2         3          1    1
3         4          1    2
4         5          1    3
5         1          2    2
6         3          2    3
7         4          2    1
8         5          2    3
9         1          3    1
10        2          3    3
11        4          3    1
12        5          3    2
13        1          4    2
14        2          4    1
15        3          4    1
16        5          4    1
17        1          5    3
18        2          5    3
19        3          5    2
20        4          5    1
```

Comment: I'm getting many errors like this

`Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Category`.
x Installation of Python not found, Python bindings not loaded.`